# gem install bundler error

Tags: software-installation, ruby, gem

I am newbie here. When I tried to install `gem install bundler`, it gave me

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Forbidden 403 (http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

So I need to install 'bundler'?

Comment: *I think*, you should ask a question, that reflects what you actually want. "what do you think?" looks like a meta-question. See [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The problem was caused by an [internet connection that wasn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674056/gem-install-bundler-error/674062#comment975517_674062).

Answer (score 1):

Doing some digging, I found that your issue is related to being behind a proxy or firewall or having a virus.

The fastest workaround is to change your gem source address from `https://rubygems.org` to `http://rubygems.org` with the following command:

```
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org
```

confirm with`y` and retry.

Comment: i terminated my wireless connection and put my internet usb instead and it is working perfectly. Thanks